# platform-independent /dev/null output sink for Java

Tags: java, stream

Other than an anonymous class (`new OutputStream() { ... }`), can anyone suggest a moral equivalent of `new FileOutputStream("/dev/null")` that also works on Windows?

In case someone's wondering 'what's this for?'

I have a program that does a consistency analysis on a file. It has a 'verbose' option. When the verbose option is on, I want to see a lot of output. The program is not in a hurry, it's a tool, so instead of writing all those extra `if` statements to test if I want the output, I just want to write it to the bit-bucket when not desired.

Comment: Why wouldn't you just want to discard the data?

Comment: @Tom Hawtin - tackline edited to explain.

Comment: Okay. I thought you "anonymous class" was just going to do what @iseletsk suggested.

Comment: For Guava users you want [`ByteStreams.nullOutputStream()`](https://google.github.io/guava/releases/snapshot/api/docs/com/google/common/io/ByteStreams.html#nullOutputStream--).

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You can use NullOutputStream from apache commons
https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-io/javadocs/api-2.4/org/apache/commons/io/output/NullOutputStream.html

Or just implement your own

```
package mypackage;

import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;

public class NullOutputStream extends OutputStream {
    public void write(int i) throws IOException {
        //do nothing
    }
}
```

Comment: (The Null Object Pattern, a special case of the Special Case Pattern.) (I'd add an override (with @Override) of `write(int,int,byte[])` for added (although probably irrelevant) performance. I've always used a single instance for the null object, but I guess you might get external locking issues (`Reader`/`Writer`s have a problem with decorators here).) (This comment contains a deliberate mistake.)

Comment: Good point about `@Override`, which would catch the deliberate mistake.

Comment: I'd want to override all the "write()" methods. I guess the JVM might be smart enough to figure out that a looped write of an array is still a no-op and treat those as no-ops, too, but I hate to depend on JVM runtime optimizations.

Answer (score 6):

Starting from JDK 11, you can use a new static method on `OutputStream` - [`nullOutputStream`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/io/OutputStream.html#nullOutputStream()).

```java
var out = OutputStream.nullOutputStream();
```

Comment: Throws a checked exception ‍♂️

Answer (score 4):

`NUL` works for Windows NT, but that doesn't work in *NIX.

```
output = new FileOutputStream("NUL");
```

Better use [`NullOutputStream`](http://commons.apache.org/io/apidocs/org/apache/commons/io/output/NullOutputStream.html) of the [Commons IO](http://commons.apache.org/io/) instead to be platform independent.

Comment: Thank you for confirmation. Didn't have a nix platform right at hand to test :)

Comment: I edited to push the `NullOutputStream` more. Is it OK so? On the other hand, you're free to edit it :)

Answer (score 0):

As long as you don't care about the slight performance difference (and you don't feel like you might run out of space), you can just use "/dev/null". On Windows, it will create a real file on whatever your current drive is (e.g., c:\dev\null).

Answer (score 0):

```java
  /**
   * Implements a "/dev/null" to consume strings without the hassle of checking the exception or closing the stream.
   *
   * @param str The string to discard
   */
  public static void discard(String str) {
    try {
      OutputStream.nullOutputStream().write(str.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8));
    } catch (IOException e) {
      throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }
  }
```