# Platform-independent way to discard out/err with ProcessBuilder

Tags: java, processbuilder, dev-null

On Unix you can discard a process' output with:

```
pb.redirectOutput(new File("/dev/null"));
```

While on Windows you instead need to use `NUL`. Is there a better option than the following snippet for supporting arbitrary platforms?

```
File devNull = new File("/dev/null");
if (devNull.exists()) {
  pb.redirectOutput(devNull);
} else {
  pb.redirectOutput(new File("NUL"));
}
```

This seems kludgy, but there isn't a `ProcessBuilder.Redirect.NULL` field to use or seemingly any other way to do this in the API.

I'm also a little concerned that this doesn't handle the non-Unix-non-Windows case (but I'm not sure if such a case exists).

I'm aware of [platform-independent /dev/null output sink for Java](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2127979/113632) and similar questions, however using a no-op `OutputStream` still requires spinning up a thread to actively discard the output - I'd prefer to let the OS do it for me.

Comment: I did the same thing after reading all the other Stack Overflow threads on this topic.  I think this is a decent solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Judging from the behavior of Python's [`subprocess`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html) module the code snippet in the question is likely sufficient. [`subprocess.DEVNULL` uses `os.devnull`](https://hg.python.org/cpython/file/3.6/Lib/subprocess.py#l768), which in turn [comes from `os.path`](https://hg.python.org/cpython/file/3.6/Lib/os.py#l92) which is defined in either [`ntpath`](https://hg.python.org/cpython/file/3.6/Lib/ntpath.py#l31) (as `nul`) or [`posixpath`](https://hg.python.org/cpython/file/3.6/Lib/posixpath.py#l37) (as `/dev/null`).

These appear to be the only paths Python supports, so similarly using either `nul` or `/dev/null` as appropriate should be sufficient in Java. There may be a more elegant, platform independent option for Java, but if so I haven't found it.